# filter nested object array in primeng table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am showing nested data in a primeng table.I have the following nested array as my api response:

```
{

    "schoolRecords": [

        {



            "grade": "7",

            "studentInfo": [

                {

                    "studentName": "Lewis",

                    "parentInfo": [

                        {

                            "phoneNo": "63789390038",
                            "parentName": "Dan",

                            "occupation": "Lawyer"

                        },
                        {

                            "phoneNo": "789928901",
                            "parentName": "Samantha",

                            "occupation": "Doctor"

                        }

                    ]
                },

                {

                    "studentName": "Lucy",

                    "parentInfo": [

                        {

                            "phoneNo": "63789390038",
                            "parentName": "Eric",

                            "occupation": "Businessman"

                        },
                        {

                            "phoneNo": "789928901",
                            "parentName": "Carly",

                            "occupation": "Lawyer"

                        }

                    ]
                }


            ]

        },

        {
            "grade": "8",

            "studentInfo": [

                {

                    "studentName": "Danny",

                    "parentInfo": [

                        {

                            "phoneNo": "63789390038",
                            "parentName": "Mathew",

                            "occupation": "Engineer"

                        },
                        {

                            "phoneNo": "789928901",
                            "parentName": "Dory",

                            "occupation": "Lawyer"

                        }

                    ]
                },

                {

                    "studentName": "Karen",

                    "parentInfo": [

                        {

                            "phoneNo": "63789390038",
                            "parentName": "Ross",

                            "occupation": "Businessman"

                        },
                        {

                            "phoneNo": "789928901",
                            "parentName": "Miley",

                            "occupation": "Housewife"

                        }

                    ]
                }


            ]

        }
    ]

}
```

I'm trying to filter this array based on the input provided by the user. For this I am using the global filter provided by primeng. However this filter is only working when the input matches the grade. How can I filter the table based on the parent's occupation/name/phoneNo. Thanks in advance for your help.

The filter I'm currently using:

```
<input type="text" pInputText  placeholder="search"
(input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
```

I tried adding a custom filter but that is not working -

```
 filterTest(value: any) {
    return this.schoolRecords.find(record => record.studentInfo.find(student => student.parentInfo.some(x => x.occupation === value)));
  }
```

template:

```
<input type="text" pInputText  placeholder="search"
(input)="filterTest($event.target.value)" style="width:auto">
```